# android sqlite doesn' support arabic

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a sqlite database on my android app and it works fine, but when I try to insert arabic language it shows squares shape like this [] [] [] [] []
I inserted the data on database using a txt file in the assets folder like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_table (id, name) VALUES (1,'احمد');
```

I tried saving the txt file in utf8 coding but the app crashes.

Comment: Could you show your code? Actually it does, as evidence look to your mobile

Comment: It seems that the file wasn't saved with the standard Unicode UTF-8 encoding, It was possibly saved by Windows Notepad, which uses a different encoding.

Comment: @Der Golem thanks for the replay, I tried saving the file with UTF-8 encoding but the app didn't work. but if I saved encoding with ANSI the app will work but the arabic letters doesn't appear.

Comment: Maybe you need a to provide a font which explicitly has the glyphs for Arabic.

Comment: Show the code that reads the txt file and executed the commands in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using this code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                ctx.getAssets().open("textFile.txt"), "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert your string to "UTF-8" before insertion like**

```
SQLiteDatabase sq = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
        try {
            String Name="نمونہ";
            c.put("Name", new String(Name.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sq.insert("tableName", null, c);
```